# Spring boot Consider defining a bean named 'servletContext' in your configuration

Tags: spring-boot, servlets, cometd, bayeux

I have a project with several modules , and it's tomcat project.I need to convert to spring boot project.

Here is a xml file with follow bean : 

    
        
        
        
            
                
                
                
                
                
                
                
            
        
        
            
                
                    
                
                
                    
                
                
                    
                
            
        
    
I have used @ImportResource("classpath:xxx.xml").

Here throws exception:

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in xxxService required a bean named 'servletContext' that could not be found.

Action:

Consider defining a bean named 'servletContext' in your configuration.

I have no idea about this problems almost three days. Please help me if you have any experiences about this, thanks a lot !

Comment: <property name="options">
            <map>
                <entry key="javax.servlet.ServletContext" value-ref="servletContext" />
                <entry key="ws.cometdURLMapping" value="/cometd/*" />
                <entry key="maxInterval" value="65000" />
                <entry key="timeout" value="30000" />
                <entry key="interval" value="15000" />
                <entry key="maxSessionsPerBrowser" value="3" />
                <entry key="jsonContext" value="org.cometd.server.Jackson1JSONContextServer" />
            </map>
        </property>

Comment: Below is the xml file options about bayeux

Comment: s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'bayeuxServer' defined in com.citi.pf.realtime.PFRealtimeServicesApplication: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'bayeuxServer' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'javax.servlet.ServletContext' available:

Comment: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}

Comment: I have delete the xml file and create bean method in the application for cometd. Below are errors.

Comment: ***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of method bayeuxServer in com.citi.pf.realtime.PFRealtimeServicesApplication required a bean of type 'javax.servlet.ServletContext' that could not be found.


Action:
Consider defining a bean of type 'javax.servlet.ServletContext' in your configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Just implement [ServletContextAware](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/ServletContextAware.html) interface instead of directly autowiring `ServletContext`

```
@Service
public class DummyService implements ServletContextAware {

    ServletContext servletContext;

    @Override
    public void setServletContext(ServletContext servletContext) {
        this.servletContext = servletContext;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The CometD integration with Spring Boot is documented here:
https://docs.cometd.org/current/reference/#_java_server_services_integration_spring_boot.

You can find a fully working example here:
https://github.com/cometd/cometd/blob/4.0.3/cometd-java/cometd-java-examples/cometd-java-examples-springboot/src/main/java/org/cometd/examples/spring/boot/CometDApplication.java.

Comment: Hi I have tried to follow this document . but there are the same problems, I guess the spring boot servlet initialization is failed. The details error is :

Comment: s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'ACometDService' defined in file [ALocateCometDService.class]:

Comment: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'bayeux' defined in class path resource [Acontext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'servletContext' while setting bean property 'options' with key [TypedStringValue: value [javax.servlet.ServletContext], target type [null]]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'servletContext' available

Comment: The CometD Spring Boot example does work. I suggest that you start from there: copy/paste it and make it work in your environment. Then you slowly change it to suit your needs. StackOverflow is not the right place to debug failures, so you are welcome to open an issue at the CometD project: https://github.com/cometd/cometd/issues.

Comment: My Spring boot version is 1.15.13 , and I debug in the application.java , it never go into any @bean method . So I guess my project doesn't initialize the servletContext , maybe it has no relationship with the Cometd server. Who can help me ?